Neither react.lazy() nor next/dynamic Works for lazy loading in next.js
I'm attempting to implement lazy loading for my components in a Next.js application, but I'm facing issues with both React.lazy() and next/dynamic. Neither approach seems to be functioning correctly.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
Using React.lazy():
'use client';
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

const Hero = lazy(() => import('../components/hero'));
const Projects = lazy(() => import('../components/projects'));
// ... (other component imports)

const LoadingFallback = () => (
  <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-16 bg-[transparent]">
    <div className="loader animate-spin rounded-full h-16 w-16 border-t-4 border-[black] border-opacity-25"></div>
  </div>
);

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className='flex items-center flex-col'> 
      <Suspense fallback={<LoadingFallback />}>
        <Hero />
        <Projects />
        {/* ... (other components) */}
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
even i am not even using and fetch req from server side...

After the first successful load,when i refresh the page,the components do not load properly, and i don't see the loading spinner...
I expect the loading spinner to display while the components are loading and that they should load without issues during subsequent page reloads...

I tried these steps...
1:Verified that the component paths are correct.
2:Added console logs to track the loading process.
3:Checked network requests in the browser's developer tools.

I sometimes see warnings related to hydration or unexpected behavior.

Any help in diagnosing why lazy loading only works for the initial render would be greatly appreciated![enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/trAkOaFy.png)


warning in console.:- Warning: Extra attributes from the server: class Error Component Stack
at html ()
at RootLayout [Server] ()
at RedirectErrorBoundary (redirect-boundary.tsx:48:5)
at RedirectBoundary (redirect-boundary.tsx:79:9)
at NotFoundErrorBoundary (not-found-boundary.tsx:32:5)
at NotFoundBoundary (not-found-boundary.tsx:117:9)
at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (dev-root-not-found-boundary.tsx:20:3)
at ReactDevOverlay (ReactDevOverlay.tsx:98:3)
at HotReload (hot-reloader-client.tsx:452:3)
at Router (app-router.tsx:300:9)
